# group by in pandas API on spark

Tags: pandas, apache-spark, pyspark, group-by, spark-koalas

I have a pandas dataframe below,

```
data = {'Team': ['Riders', 'Riders', 'Devils', 'Devils', 'Kings',
   'kings', 'Kings', 'Kings', 'Riders', 'Royals', 'Royals', 'Riders'],
   'Rank': [1, 2, 2, 3, 3,4 ,1 ,1,2 , 4,1,2],
   'Year': [2014,2015,2014,2015,2014,2015,2016,2017,2016,2014,2015,2017],
   'Points':[876,789,863,673,741,812,756,788,694,701,804,690]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Here df is a Pandas dataframe.

I am trying to convert this dataframe to pandas API on spark

```
import pyspark.pandas as ps
pdf = ps.from_pandas(df)
print(type(pdf))
```

Now the dataframe type is '<class 'pyspark.pandas.frame.DataFrame'>
'
No I am applying group by function on pdf like below,

```
for i,j in pdf.groupby("Team"):
    print(i)
    print(j)
```

I am getting an error below like

```
KeyError: (0,)
```

Not sure this functionality will work on pandas API on spark ?

Comment: It wont because pyspark, groupby method has a different name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pyspark pandas does not implement all functionalities as-is because Spark has distributed architecture. Hence operations like rowwise iterations etc. can be subjective.

If you want to print the groups, then pyspark pandas code:

```py
pdf.groupby("Team").apply(lambda g: print(f"{g.Team.values[0]}\n{g}"))
```

is equivalent to pandas code:

```py
for name, sub_grp in df.groupby("Team"):
    print(name)
    print(sub_grp)
```

**Reference to source code**

If you scan the source code, you will find that there is no `__iter__()` implementation for pyspark pandas: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/_modules/pyspark/pandas/groupby.html

but the iterator yields (group_name, sub_group) for pandas: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v1.5.1/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L816

**Documentation reference to iterate groups**

pyspark pandas : https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.pandas/groupby.html?highlight=groupby#indexing-iteration

pandas : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/groupby.html#iterating-through-groups

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see the given groups just define your pyspark df correctly and utilize the print statement with the given results of the generator. Or just use pandas

```
for i in df.groupby("Team"):
    print(i)
```

Or

```
for i in pdf.groupBy("Team"):
    print(i)
```

Comment: if pandas Api on Spark extends the functionality of pandas . why i am not able to see the results?